# Unity3d canvas position not reliable

Tags: unity-game-engine

I creating a new UI-Text but the position is to far from my game take place, how i can move it so it fit with the game?

My game and Where the canvas now[image]

Comment: You should add a screen cap of the Canvas inspector settings.

Comment: Did you figure it out buddy?